# Notifications being blocked

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, cloud

I don't know is this is the place to ask or even if this is a VC issue.

I am using firebase cloud messaging.

The page works fine and the messaging works as expected

However, when I debug the page in VCODE using F5 or SHIFT F5 the notifications are blocked

Has anyone got any recommendations where I can start looking

So far I have reinstalled both CHROME and VSCODE with no success

Thanks

Comment: Any thing separate in debug environment ? May be environment variables or some special parameters to launch command ? Comparing the dev and debug environments could help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the issue.

It was the configuration of the launch.json file

I had to include "port":443, in it

I have no idea how it changed